# How to store all the data loaded from multiple files in one file after a for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have 47 different files for 47 locations. Each file contains 3000x1 data. I want to load all the files together. Then I want to check the unique values of each file (in this case I will have 47 sets of unique data sets) and want to save all the unique files (47 sets of unique data in one file. Then I want to check the probability. In this case I will have 47 sets of probability files for 47 sets of unique data files. Now I want to store all the 47 sets of probability files in another file. When I am using the programme below, I am only able to store one set of unique data and one set of probability data (i.e for 47th location only). How can I store for all the locations together in this case? Please guide. (I know there are some problems with the loop but I am not able to fix it)

```
for location=1:47;
    load(['data_sets/data_loc_' num2str(location) , '_trial.mat'])
    un_rssi= unique(RSSI_all);
    normhist= hist(RSSI_all,size(un_rssi,1))/sum(hist(RSSI_all)); 
end
```

Comment: You want to store the data from all 47 files in one single file, stored in a single location? Besides, `hist` is a deprecated function. Using `histogram` is recommended.

Comment: yes I want to store all the data from 47 locations in one file. I want to make 2 files. One file contains the data sets of all the unique data from 47 files and another one contains their respective probabilities.

Comment: Utilize the optional output of [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) to load your data into a structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
un_rssi = cell(47,1); % initialise for speed
normhist = cell(47,1);
for location=1:47;
    load(['data_sets/data_loc_' num2str(location) , '_trial.mat'])
    un_rssi{location,1}= unique(RSSI_all); % store in the cell
    normhist{location,:}= hist(RSSI_all,size(un_rssi,1))/sum(hist(RSSI_all)).'; % need a column vector
end

un_rssi = cell2mat(un_rssi); % switch to a matrix
normhist = cell2mat(normhist);

dlmwrite('YourFile1.txt',un_rssi); % Write to file
dlmwrite('YourFile2.txt',normhist);
```

You can of course use whatever file writing function you like, I just used `dlmwrite` as an example.